# jQuery data-options truncates when the value is a French name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div in my html,

```
<div id="datadiv"></div>
```

In my script i update the div(datadiv) by sending a request to my server.

```
<script>

  $.ajax({
  url: 'getusers.do',
  dataType: 'html',
  success: function( data ) {
      $("#datadiv").html(data);
      console.log($("#namespan").data("options").name); //undefined 
  }
  })

</script>
```

Java Code:

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
String username = "";

// The below code runs in a for loop. I have many usernames.
username = "François L'Écuyer"; // This is a French name. 
sb.append("<span id=\"namespan\" data-options='{\"name\":\""+username+"\"}'>"+username+"</span>");
//Loop ends

return sb.toString(); //This value is returned to the ajax success.
```

When i get the name which is stored in the data. I get undefined. The data-options gets truncated and broken.

Comment: It's not the French name, it's the space between "François" and "L'Écuyer". Remove it and it works. I'm not sure jQuery officially supports object literals in `data-` attributes in the first place, mind you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let jquery handle it. Try constructing the element using jquery instead of constructing as a string:

```
var username = "François L'Écuyer";
var temp_data = $('<span/>', {'id': 'namespan', 
                            'data-options' : '{"name":"'+username+'"}',
                            'text':'UserName'});
$("#datadiv").html(temp_data);
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WLLzs/)**

or stringify the object

```
var data = { name: username } ;
var temp_data = $('<span/>', {
    'id': 'namespan',
    'text': 'UserName',
    'data-options': JSON.stringify(data)
});

$("#datadiv").html(temp_data);
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8gaDQ/)**

**Update**

Proper encoding to add on proper escaping should make it right. instead of using `\"` to wrap the data attribute value JSON's key/value use `&quot;` and try something like:

```
'<span id="namespan" data-options="{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;'+username+'&quot;}">UserName</span>'
```

or probably in java:

```
"<span id=\"namespan\" data-options=\"{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;"+username+"&quot;}\">"+username+"</span>"
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/92D8a/)

Comment: That's marginally better, but it'll still break if the username has double quotes. In general it's a bad idea to hand-craft JSON. It'd be better to use `.data()` to add the data to the element: http://jsfiddle.net/WLLzs/1/

Comment: @Juhana yeah true, but you can stringify the object as well which would be better i would say... Because adding data using data api does not add it as attribute (Depends on if it is needed at all though), it is just stored in the internal data-cache

Comment: Actually the temp_data html is constructed in java and its the response in ajax success. So i could not use the suggestion mentioned above.

Comment: @PSL Which I would count as a plus, but whatever.

Comment: @Jeevi I can't see how that would prevent you from doing it. If you don't know how, you should show your actual code.

Comment: @Juhana i have updated my actual code how i am sending data from server.

Comment: @Jeevi Try to do this way.. http://jsfiddle.net/JMU5j/ You can translate it into java. `\"` is not really escaped in html i.e for javascript. instead use `&quot;` Try `"<span id='namespan' data-options='{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;"+username+"&quot;}'>"+username+"</span>"` something like this.

Comment: @Jeevi You should really return raw data with JSON (see e.g. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338586/a-better-java-json-library)) and handle it in JavaScript instead of building HTML in Java. Saves a lot of headaches.

Comment: @PSL Your java code of the span html work fine for me. Thanks for your reply.